# php in/out from bash while another script running

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, terminal

PHP script is launching some executable via bash (shell_exec), and must read/write to them...
Launched executable is waiting for input, but sometimes throws messages to terminal.
I know how to read this "stream" but how to write?

Comment: `shell_exec()` doesn't let you write to the process, it just returns the output at the end. Take a look at [Expect](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.expect.php)

Comment: @Barmar interesting thing... i guess that is exactly what i need, thank u!